# Compare two matrix values

Tags: python

I have a condition and need to compare values. `AV` is an arary and `53` is a number. Even if I create the `array = 53 * len(AV)`, python has a problem.

`The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambigous.`

What should I do to solve this if condition?

```
def app_visc(PV, YP, Dbit, DP, ROP):
    vcut = 1/((1-(Dbit/DP)**2)*(0.64 + np.divide(18.16, ROP)))
    vslipguess = 3                              #Guess
    vcrit = vcut + vslipguess

    AV = PV + np.divide(5*YP*(Dbit-DP),vcrit)

    if AV <= 53:  #TODO: porównanie wartości macierzy
        vslip = 0.0051*AV + 3.006
    else: 
        vslip = 0.02554*(AV-53) + 3.28
    return vslip
```

Comment: Please give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): a snippet of code that's still small, but enough that we can actually run it (which also includes having input data). Also show us the whole exception, not just a description of it, and what result you wanted.

Comment: Anyway, the big question here is: What do you want `if AV <= 53:` to do? Do you want to do something if _all_ values of AV are under 53? If _any_ value is under 53? Or _for each_ value that's under 53? Those are all reasonable things to do, and numpy can't guess which one you want, and that's why it gives you that error. (Well, the proximate reason is just that `ndarray.__bool__` raises the exception you see whenever its len is >1, but the reason it was designed that way was because the designers couldn't guess what you might want.)

Comment: I think I edited the `array = 53 * len(AV)` part right. If not, please correct me.

Comment: One more thing: You should _look at_ the entire exception. After the part you cut off, it actually gives you a hint: `Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) three different things you could mean by `if AV <= 53:`, and they'd all have very different effects. So, numpy was designed not to try to guess what you mean, and instead raise this error to force you to be explicit.

If you want to do something if *all* values are under 53, you use the `all` function or method:

```
if np.all(a<=53):  # or (a<=53).all()
```

If you want to do something if *any* values are under 53, you use the `any` function or method:

```
if np.any(a<=53):  # or (a<=53).any()
```

If you want to do something *for each* value under 53, and you want to do that with a pure-Python loop, you just loop over the bool array:

```
for i, flag in enumerate(a<=53):
    if flag:
```

But of course you almost always want to do the looping inside numpy instead:

```
a[a<=53]
```

That's just an array with all the values of `a` that are `<= 53`.

---

If you want to understand exactly how this is happening, you can break things into steps. While `if a<=53:` loops pretty simple, nothing in numpy is quite as simple as it looks. Try this:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 50, 100, 50, 0])
>>> a<=53
array([True, True, False, True, True])
```

So `a<=53` is actually an array of 5 bools—each one tells you whether the corresponding member of `a` is `<=53`.

And if you try to use that as if it were a single `bool`:

```
>>> bool(a<=53)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

That's exactly your error.