# Comparing same positional integers in two arrays in a dice game

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am looking to have a dice game where a user is asked how many times the two dice are to be rolled. Based on pairs within the rolls the user is awarded money to their total.

The problem I have is that I am not able to compare the same positional values within the arrays using my current `for` loop.

The error I am getting is: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def dice_game():

    rolls = int(input("how many times would you like to roll the dice: "))
    dice_value1 = np.random.randint( 1, 7, rolls)
    print(dice_value1)
    dice_value2 = np.random.randint( 1, 7, rolls)
    print(dice_value2)
    return dice_value1, dice_value2

result1, result2 = dice_game()

def dice_game_analysis(x,y):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
          if i == y:
              if i == 1:
                  total = 0
              if i <= 4:
                  total += x
              if i >= 5:
                  total += 2*x
    print(total)

dice_game_analysis(result1, result2)
```

Comment: `np.random.randint` gives you an *array* of random numbers, `i` is a single integer. What did you expect from `i == y`? Did you read any of the (many) other questions that include *"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"*?

Comment: As a side note, did you really want those `if`s in `dice_game_analysis` to be independent like that instead of `elif`? Because whenever you roll a 1, both `i == 1` and `i <= 4` will be true, so you'll first reset `total = 0` and then do `total += x`. Even if that _is_ what you want, it's a bit confusing to read, so you might still want to change it to `elif`s (and then change the `total = 0` to `total = x`).

Comment: Anyone know the canonical dup for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369836/compare-two-matrix-values/49369983#49369983 is a recent one I happened to have in my history, but probably not the best one.